# chef pass in ssh key securely through aws opswork

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I want to take my private ssh key and place it inside the server, this key connects to github.

Now I don't want to store this key in my chef recipe repository, I want to pass the key with the opswork external json.

My problem is how do I store a multi line key in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the new lines with \n should work.

E.g.

```
{
  "key": "line1\nline2\nline3"
}
```

The alternate is to store the key in a place that only the opsworks stack can access, e.g. S3.

Comment: did \n, but when I output it in to a file template, I get the \n inside the file and it doesn't work

Comment: Strange, I tried testing it with chef-solo (which isn't quite opsworks I guess) and it worked as expected for me.

Which version of Chef are you using in opsworks and can you post a snippet of the code that outputs the attribute?

Comment: how do you output the key variable in the template?